# How to add image and title in the centre of core plot pie chart?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-plot, cppiechart

I would need to add image and label in the centre of donut pie chart. I used core plot to draw pie chart. How do I get the centre of pie chart?

Please see the image 
[Donut pie chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNDgs.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the coordinates in the `centerAnchor` by the corresponding part of the size of the plot area `bounds` and add that to the `x` or `y` coordinate of the bounds `origin`. You can use the calculated point as the anchor for a layer annotation.

This is how the pie chart calculates the center when drawing the plot:

```
CPTPlotArea *thePlotArea = self.plotArea;

CGRect plotAreaBounds = thePlotArea.bounds;
CGPoint anchor        = self.centerAnchor;
CGPoint centerPoint   = CPTPointMake(plotAreaBounds.origin.x + plotAreaBounds.size.width * anchor.x,
                                     plotAreaBounds.origin.y + plotAreaBounds.size.height * anchor.y);
centerPoint = [self convertPoint:centerPoint fromLayer:thePlotArea];
if ( self.alignsPointsToPixels ) {
    centerPoint = CPTAlignPointToUserSpace(context, centerPoint);
}
```